# Page objects in Protractor / Jasmine cause error: Failed: Cannot read property 'sendKeys' of undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, bdd

I'm trying to get page objects to work for Protractor and Jasmine, and I'm getting "Failed: Cannot read property 'sendKeys' of undefined" when I try to use page objects.

I have read similar posts but they do not provide any answers for me or the situation is too different to be of any help to me.

I've checked every character of the two files. It appears that the test cannot see the page object file for some reason. BTW Protractor is installed Globally so I don't need to include it in the script.

Everything was working prior to converting to using the "test_page.js" file instead of the hard-coded values.

This is from a tutorial where his code was working fine.

/superhero-tests/test/test_spec.js file

```
//require() is a notjs function - https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/
const TestPage = require("../page-objects/test.page")
 
//This file runs the browser and executes the script.
describe('Super Hero Page',function(){
 
    var testPage
 
    //Jasmine: Before each test case, do something
    beforeEach(function(){    
        
        testPage = new TestPage()
 
        //Protractor: For non-angular sites
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
 
        //Open URL
        browser.get('file:///C:/projects/Protractor/Superhero/index.html') 
        
    })
 
    //Jasmine: After each test case, do something
    afterEach(function(){
 
        //Timer to prevent immediate closure of the window
        //browser.sleep(5000)
    })
 
    it('should load the correct URL',function(){
 
        //Enter text into form fields
        testPage.emailFld.sendKeys('a@b.com')
        testPage.passwordFld.sendKeys('Test.123')
 
        //Check some text in an element
        expect(testPage.loginTitleTxt.getText()).toEqual('Welcome. Please Log In.')
                
        //Check a HTML element's attribute
        expect( testPage.emailFld.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('a@b.com')
        
        //Non-precise matching - don't use with an empty string, will pass
        //expect( testPage.loginTitleTxt.getText() ).toContain('Welcome.')
 
    })
})
```

/superhero-tests/page-objects/test_page.js file

```
var TestPage = function(){}
 
TestPage.prototype = Object.create({},{
    emailFld: { get: function(){ return element( by.id('loginEmail') ) } }, //this is a page object
    passswordFld: { get: function(){ return element( by.id('loginPassword') ) } }, //this is a page object
    loginTitleTxt: { get: function(){ return element( by.id('login-title') ) } } //this is a page object
})
 
module.exports = TestPage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found alternative Page Object code which works (tutorial linked below):

**The page object:**

```
var TestPage = (function () {
    function TestPage() {
        this.emailFld = element( by.id('loginEmail') )
        this.passswordFld = element( by.id('loginPassword') )
        this.loginTitleTxt = element( by.id('login-title') )
    }

    return TestPage;

})();

module.exports = TestPage;
```

**The spec(test) file:**

```
//Test for Login page

var TestPage = require("../page-objects/test.page")

//Appears in command line
describe('Login page tests', function(){

    var test = new TestPage();

    //Executed before the tests
    beforeEach(function(){
        //Protractor: For non-angular sites
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true

        //Open URL
        browser.get('file:///C:/projects/Protractor/Superhero/index.html')
    })

    //Executed after the tests
    afterEach(function(){

        //Timer so we can see what is going on
        //browser.sleep(5000)        

    })

    //The test statements themselves
    it('should display all the Login page elements',function(){
        
        //With page object
        expect(  test.emailFld.getAttribute('placeholder')  ).toEqual('Enter email')
    })

})
```

It seems to make better use of the initial function and then do the module.exports at the end. The only other difference I can see is that they used var not const in the test file, but I don't know this would change much.

https://teamgaslight.com/blog/getting-started-with-protractor-and-page-objects-for-angularjs-e2e-testing

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of tutorial would overcomplicate the logic so much. Try this

/superhero-tests/page-objects/test_page.js file

```
module.exports = function() {
  this.emailFld = element( by.id('loginEmail') )
  this.passswordFld = element( by.id('loginPassword') )
  this.loginTitleTxt = element( by.id('login-title') )
}
```

Also keep in mind, the tutorial teaches you to outdated syntax of protractor 3 or 4, which is no longer used since protractor 7 was released a few years ago

Comment: It's a Udemy tutorial. It does seem very complicated, and, if that was the way to do it I was in two minds about just doing it the repetitious way. Thanks for the code. I would like to know why you can't just replace the reference to the field with a bog-standard variable though?

Comment: I still get the same error though after adding the code. BTW. The tutorial is "Website Automation Testing for Beginners with Protractor".

Comment: get a refund, I'm serious. Udemy offers it within first 30 days I think. At this point the problem can be anywhere, I can't spend more time. The code quality is just very low. Sorry